# UPS battery replacement

Tags: batteries, ups

For the UPS model Niky 900 by Daker, I'd like to replace the original [CSB HR1234W F2](http://www.csb-battery.com/english/01_product/02_detail.php?fid=7&pid=28) battery with something I can buy on amazon.it, e.g. FIAMM models: could you suggest what are the relevant parameters to match, in particular how do I compare the 34W datum for the above model with more common Ah specs? 
Is e.g. the model [FIAMM FG 20721](http://www.fiamm.com/en/europe/industrial-batteries/products/fg-@-emea-sa.aspx) (12V - 7,2 AH - 7AH) good enough?
(I've made a 'translation' from W to Ah looking at [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100251/convert-watt-to-ampere-hour-for-battery)) Should I opt for a 9Ah?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 7Ah battery should work, but it will provide less energy than the original battery which is better suited for high power discharge.

The weird part about CSB model numbers is that for most series they show the voltage and capacity (GP1272 is 12V 7.2Ah),  but for the HR and HRL series the model number shows the voltage and the power that a single cell can provide for 15 minutes. So, your HR1234W battery can provide 204W (34W/cell * 6 cells) for 15 minutes.

And it's even written on the battery too - 12V 34W/Cell/1.67V/15Min.

Answer (score 0):

`W` is a unit for energy, while `Ah` is a unit for charge capacity. You can't directly convert these units to each other. A low capacity battery can supply higher power if it has lower internal resistance.

And, I don't understand your hesitation for selecting a battery. I strongly believe that both batteries can supply 34W power without any problem at normal environment conditions. Purchase the highest capacity battery according to your budget, so that your device will run longer when there is a blackout.

Comment: Beware using too high a battery capacity, though - the charger may be overloaded trying to recharge it after a long discharge.

Comment: All quality chargers have internal current limit feed back though.

Comment: The purpose of my question was finding a battery as similar as possible to the original one: do you think it is closer to the 7Ah or 9Ah model?

Comment: Considering that the 20721's fifteen-minute discharge rate is 146 watts (see lower table in right document), I'd say it's overkill and the 9Ah version would be even more so.

Comment: @TDHofstetter thanks for the tip; could you point out a model by FIAMM (or, as far as I'm concerned, available on amazon.it) you think is going to work fine?

Comment: For a CSB HR or HRL series battery the Watt rating is the power that a single cell can provide for 15 minutes (kinda weird unit of capacity).

Comment: jj...p, you do realize that the original battery is available on (at least the central) Amazon, and may therefore be available on Amazon.it? http://www.amazon.com/Replacement-CSB-HR1234W-Battery-Units/dp/B00DZVSTTK